# "A bit" and "a little" can only be used in front of an adjective when the adjective is being used after a verb such as be, but if a noun follows

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, uncountable-nouns

Page 557 of Collins English Usage reads

> **A bit** and **a little** can only be used in front of an adjective when the adjective is being used after a verb such as *be*, but not
> with an adjective that is in front of a noun, ***✳**it was a bit
> unpleasant experience*.

Is it then only correct when the noun is uncountable or plural?

Comment: You missed the "in" after the verb. It's not the same pattern.

Comment: In your new example, "to skin" is not a noun. It is also not the same pattern.

Comment: That rule is correct. The experience was a bit unpleasant. NOT: It was a bit unpleasant experience. It's not about the noun. It about where you place "a bit [adjective]" in a sentence.